# Gradle publish multiple independent artifacts

Tags: gradle, ivy

I've got a project that builds using Gradle and the ivy-publish plugin.  In addition to building a JAR, build.gradle also executes a run task that executes XmlFileGenerator.main(), which generates 5 XML files (call them A, B, C, D, and E).  I'm looking to publish each of these XML files to our Ivy repository; each should have the same group and version but a different module and a different filename, and each should have its own ivy.xml that lists only itself.

I'm able to set the filename of the file that's published, but the module name remains the same as my project's name, and as a result all of my XML files are published under the same module name instead of under independent ones.

So for example, I want A.xml to be published at `{myLocalIvyRootDir}\my-group\A\{version}\xmls\A-{version}.xml` and I want B.xml to be published at `{myLocalIvyRootDir}\my-group\B\{version}\xmls\B-{version}.xml`.  But instead A is published at `{myLocalIvyRootDir}\my-group\my-project\{version}\xmls\A-{version}.xml` and B is published alongside it at `{myLocalIvyRootDir}\my-group\my-project\{version}\xmls\B-{version}.xml`.

Here's the relevant subset of build.gradle (showing only A but not B-E):

```
apply plugin: 'ivy-publish'

group = 'my-group'

publishing {
    publications {
        ivy(IvyPublication) {
            artifact jar
        }
        aXml(IvyPublication) {
            artifact('target/A.xml') {
                name = 'A'
                extension = 'xml'
                type = 'xml'
            }
        }
    }
}

mainClassName = 'my-group.my-project.XmlFileGenerator'
```

I've tried defining the module property on the publication with this code:

```
        aXml(IvyPublication) {
            module 'A'
            artifact('target/A.xml') {
                name = 'A'
                extension = 'xml'
                type = 'xml'
            }
        }
```

But I get the following error message:

`> org.gradle.api.internal.MissingMethodException: Could not find method module() for arguments [A] on org.gradle.api.publish.ivy.internal.publication.DefaultIvyPublication_Decorated@32384c50.`

And I've tried changing the rootProject.name dynamically with code like:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        ivy(IvyPublication) {
            artifact jar
        }
        project.metaClass.getName {"A"}
        aXml(IvyPublication) {
            artifact('target/A.xml') {
                name = 'A'
                extension = 'xml'
                type = 'xml'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That produced no errors, but also no change in behavior.

I feel like I'm probably just missing something small, but don't know what it is.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this particular project was still pointing to Gradle 1.6, before these properties were made available (they were added in 1.7).  So all that was needed was to point to 1.7, and everything worked as intended.